# How to remove html tags in zoho creator

Tags: php, zoho

Please see input

```
Var = "Hi <p> I am Sunita </p> but i am big";
```

But i need this output by zoho

```
var = "Hi I am Sunita but i am big";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.removeElement(<value>);
```

---

> `<list>` refers to the list name from where the element needs to be
>   removed.
>   `<value>` refers to the element to be removed from the list.

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/remove-element.html#List_Manipulations_-_Remove_Element

Comment: thanks, But tag is not fix , if any tag in this var than not fix only <p> tag

Comment: Input : <html>Hi <p> I am<b> Sunita</b> </p> but i am<u> big</u></html>

Comment: Please suggest answer from above input

Comment: I guess you'll have to use `removeElement` for other  tags

Comment: how to use lots of tag this removeElement